# Removing the time from datetime output (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Remove the time from this code.

Current Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

print("Today's date:", date)
```

Output:

```
Today's date: 2022-05-11 18:44:01.832558
```

Desired Output:

```
Today's date: 2022-05-11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `date` value is actually a `datetime` object.  Call `date()` on it to convert it to just a `date`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.today().date())
2022-05-12
```

Comment: I don't know if you meant to put "datetime." twice, I removed one and then it worked.

Comment: You imported `datetime.datetime` as `datetime` (`from datetime import datetime`); I just imported the `datetime` module (`import datetime`).